# cs-Cz locale and JavaScript new Date Constructor doesn't allow for shorthand date

Tags: javascript, date, locale

So I'm trying to follow the docs here on MDN regarding the date options for formatting

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

For the cs-cz locale, I want the month to be in "short" hand form when writing a date such as

`19. 12. 2012` instead of `19. pro 201`

This code works for locales such as en-us or it-it (italy) and others.

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0, 200));
var options = { month: 'short', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'};
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-us', options).format(date));
```

Prints out `Dec 19, 2012`

Can anyone help me with getting the cs-cz locale to work.  This code

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0, 200));
var options = { month: 'short', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'};
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('cs-cz', options).format(date));
```

prints out

`19. 12. 2012` instead of `19. pro 201`

I'd like `19. pro 201` using the JavaScript Date Function.  This is all dynamic in my code based on 13 locales and czech is the only one giving me trouble.

Comment: The actual format created by a particular language code is not standardised, which is the whole point of "localisation". It also highlights that formatting is very much a personal opinion: a short month in Czech to whoever programmed that implementation of Intl.DateTimeFormat is different to your opinion of what it should be. It also highlights that calling a language code "locale" is a misnomer.

Answer (score 1):

A weird conundrum for sure. As it turns out, if you include the `week` format in the options object it provides the output you seek. So the code below simple uses that and then removes the week name from the string.

I did not modify the year, and will leave that up to you, but I do believe this solves your problem and answers your question.

```js
const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0, 200));
const out = date.toLocaleDateString('cs-CZ', options).split(' ').splice(1).join(' ');
console.log(out);
```

Comment: Yea thanks - that's the route I ended up going.  I guess there's a bug within the JavaScript Date Constructor.  Thanks was just hoping there was something else wrong.

Comment: You could always file a bug with TC-39. https://github.com/tc39/ecma262

Comment: @gary1410—nothing to do with the Date constructor. The options for *Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString* are based on ECMA-402, which is an entirely different specification to ECMAScript (ECMA-262) and is about formatting, not constructing. ;-)